# setFastestInterval(long milis) not working

Tags: android, geolocation, android-maps-v2, location-client

I want to slow the update rates as soon as I got a location precise enough for my needs:

```
    @Override
public void slowUpdateRate() {
    /*
     * Set the update interval 
     */
    Dbg.v(TAG,"****************************");
    Dbg.e(TAG, "-- SLOW update rate");
    Dbg.v(TAG,"****************************");
    stopUpdates();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1500000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(150000);
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
```

The method is called but I still got updates every 3 seconds and a half. I have a ViewPager with a maps 2.0 fragment but I did `mapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(false);`

How do I slow updates?  Why FastestInterval is not working?

---

EDIT: I test my slow updates on the dummy application provided by Google docs and it works ok. I added a LogCat getFastestInterval and getInterval and I got the 15 and 30 seconds I was expecting in the test context. BUT the update rate is still freaking too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this !

The mistake is mine and can be resume in this

DO **NOT** CALL AGAIN `mLocationClient.requestUpdates(mLocationRequest,this);`

Also, remember that the default fastest interval is your normal interval/6 .

Comment: [LocationClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html) is deprecated. Look at this answer for current options: [LocationManager or Location Service API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266362/android-google-maps-api-location/27195920#27195920)

Comment: thanks for commenting. Was it deprecated one year ago ? 
Right now I am using LocationManager. note, you have to considered that the new FusionLocation api are part of Google services which might not be available for some projects.